# Chosing the right datetime format for the date column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe **df1** that looks like this:

```
id  date    value
0   C1  1/1/17  31
1   C1  1/2/17  35
2   C1  1/3/17  32
3   C1  1/6/17  36
4   C1  1/7/17  35
5   C1  1/8/17  34
6   C1  1/10/17 33
7   C2  1/1/17  225
8   C2  1/2/17  223
9   C2  1/3/17  223
10  C2  1/6/17  220
11  C2  1/7/17  222
12  C2  1/8/17  225
13  C2  1/10/17 224
14  C3  1/8/17  340
```

The **dtypes** are as follows:

```
id       object
date     object
value     int64
dtype: object
```

I am trying to convert the **date** columns dtype to datetime:

```
  df1['date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%d%b%Y')
```

This fails with;

```
    ValueError: time data '1/1/17' does not match format '%d%b%Y' (match)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) without parameters:

```
df1['date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
print (df1)
    id       date  value
0   C1 2017-01-01     31
1   C1 2017-01-02     35
2   C1 2017-01-03     32
3   C1 2017-01-06     36
4   C1 2017-01-07     35
5   C1 2017-01-08     34
6   C1 2017-01-10     33
7   C2 2017-01-01    225
8   C2 2017-01-02    223
9   C2 2017-01-03    223
10  C2 2017-01-06    220
11  C2 2017-01-07    222
12  C2 2017-01-08    225
13  C2 2017-01-10    224
14  C3 2017-01-08    340
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked fine:

```
    df1['date']= pd.to_datetime(df1['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')
```